# How to modify the language switcher block to only use the language code instead of its full name?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

In the Language selection block, I have only the possibility to use the full language name. How can I change it to use the language code, for example *FR* instead of *French*?

Comment: @Vasmir, this is not a good practice, since all the modifications will be lost upon future update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to insert this snippet in your .theme file

In this example I am using bartik as a theme.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function bartik_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['plugin_id'] == 'language_block:language_interface') {
    foreach ($variables['content']['#links'] as $key => $value) {
      $variables['content']['#links'][$key]['title'] = strtoupper($key);
    }
  }
}
```

Please, let me know if this solution works for you.

Best regards,

Oleg

Comment: thx, that worked!

Comment: I am glad that it worked, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

An issue for bringing that as settings in Drupal core: https://www.drupal.org/node/2135379